# How to import new matrialized css 1.0 alpha version to angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, materialize

Need to import new matrialized css 1.0 alpha version to angular 4. I can write below code to make things work

```
<a onclick="M.toast({html: 'I am a toast'})" class="btn">Toast!</a>
```

But i want to import the materialized module into the typescript

import {M} from 'materilized-css';

so that i can use in some function

```
function test() {
  // some condition 
  M.toast({html: 'I am a toast'})
}
```

I have added the script file path in .angular-cli.json.

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js"
  ]
```

How can i do so. Need help in this or there is any other way to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how it works.

First, you need to add the JS import, either in your index.html file (and you declare your library as an asset), either in your angular-cli.json file.

You should do the latter one. You must put your script into the `scripts` property of your angular-cli file.

Once it's done, in your components, you need to declare a global variable as so

```
declare var M: any;
```

Now in your component, you will have access to this variable, as you would in JS.

If you have any question, feel free to ask !

**EDIT** In details

**angular-cli.json**

```
"styles": [
  "You should have some styles in this property",
  "Add your dependency like so"
  "../node_modules/PATH/TO/MATERIALIZE.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "You should have some scripts in this property",
  "Add your dependency like so"
  "../node_modules/PATH/TO/MATERIALIZE.js"
],
```

**In your component**

```
// First, you have your import zone
import { ... } from '...';

// You put your declare here
declare var M: any;

// Then you have the component
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements onInit { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, for the ans. But where exactly i need to add the declare var M: any;. I am totally new for node js and angular. So kindly help me out.

Comment: import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var M: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  test() {
    M.toast({ html: 'I am a toast!', classes: 'rounded' });
  }
} and in HTML i have added as below: <a class="btn" ng-click="test()">Toast!</a>

Comment: Did you add it to your angular-cli file ?

Comment: Yes, i have added. Please check in the qus description i hv mentioned how i did.

Comment: Well dumb question but we never know : is this package in your package.json file ?

Comment: I did mistake in html part. I should be doing (click)="test()". Anyways thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Well no problem, remember to mark the question as resolved !